# Cells don't resize when user resizes NSTableViews columns?

Tags: cocoa, resize, osx-mavericks, nstableview

I have found that the text in a table view doesn't grow when the user resizes the column. (Or for that matter shrink if he shrinks the column, because the truncation ellipses then vanish.) Having gathered that this is something to do with constraints, my solution has been to uncheck Use Auto Layout (in the xib's file inspector). Not a big deal, but it comes just when I was beginning to think I might have mastered Autolayout.

Is that really the only way to do this?

The table is view-based, and gets its data from Core Data via an array controller. The text is displayed in an NSTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as you have found out yourself.

If you want to know/learn more about NSTableview-behavior search for "TableViewVariableRowHeights" and "TableViewLinks" in Apples documentation and download the samples.

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to be answered in:

[How to Expand NSTableCellView Width When Resizing Column in NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505903/how-to-expand-nstablecellview-width-when-resizing-column-in-nstableview)

summary: add horizontal constraints to the table view cell

see the link for screenshots