# How to Expand NSTableCellView Width When Resizing Column in NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview

I am trying to display a path in my table view. Both columns of the table view on the left side are the same for testing/demonstration purposes. Notice how the leftmost path is truncated:
[image: Initial table view]

When I expand the column, the (truncated) table view cell doesn't expand with the column:
[image: Resized column width]

My question is how would I go about resizing the cell when I resize the table view column?

Comment: No unfortunately, but there is sample code provided by apple that has something like my view that does work. If I get back to working on this project I think I am just going to borrow some code from the working Apple sample.

Answer (score 13):

Found a solution, what you want to do is add a few constraints

Step 1:
go to the table cell view for said column

[image: Step 1]

Step 2:
Change these constraints

[image: Step 2]

Step 3:
Change these constraints aswell

[image: Step 3]

Step 4: run your app and look at your nice table :-D

Comment: Just as a clarification here, 'cause I did a double-take when I saw the screenshots, the constraints you want to add are:
Vertical Centre in Container,
Pin Left Edge (3),
and Pin Right Edge (3). 

You do not need horizontal centre - that will happen automatically because left and right edges are both pinned. Also note that width and height, and top and bottom edges, are not active despite having numbers in them - you don't need those.

Thanks for pointing out the correct item to constrain though.