# NSTableView - truncated fields, don't resize with table column?

Tags: resize, nstableview

I created my first OSX Application, with a single window linked to a view controller in the Storyboard.

The view controller has several elements including a default tableview, View-based.

I downloaded the sample app from Apple called TableViewPlayground to see what's wrong with my tableview because a few weird things happen:

1) I have 4 columns (text only), whenever I select the table view cell element in the View Controller Scene tree (on the left), it selects my cell but the RESIZE squares don't appear, whilst they appear in the Apple application.

2) In the Size inspector in my application, the Autoresizing elements don't appear, whilst they appear in the Apple application

3) Even if I put constraints to my cells to make them autosize, they are never respected.

Result: my table columns resize perfectly, can move around, etc... BUT my cells don't resize in width and are always truncated whatever the size...it seems to be fixed to a certain width, that's it

I even tried using a different cell type (Image + text) and in that case, it's even worse because the image doesn't show up at all

Very strange....

Please help me, I used to develop in iOS and never had any problem. Here, I'm stuck.

If you need more info, screenshots etc... tell me

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27313135/1438339

Comment: Thx a lot mate, it works.