# Auto Resizing of NSTableView Content Not Working

Tags: xcode, macos, autolayout, appkit

Along the same lines as [How to Expand NSTableCellView Width When Resizing Column in NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505903/how-to-expand-nstablecellview-width-when-resizing-column-in-nstableview) - but the solution there isn't working for me...

I've got a Mac app in Xcode 12.3 with some table views which adjust their width according to the size of the window - but I cannot get the table contents to adjust their width to fill the columns.

Here's a view debug of what I'm seeing:

[image: View Debug of NSTableView]

The NSTableCellView width is 287, but the NSTableRowView is 343.

I've got *Autoresizes Subviews* turned on all the way down the hierarchy, and I've got leading and trailing constraints from the Table View Cell to its superview - but I can't get it working.

Any clues? Many thanks!

Comment: What is the width of the column? Is the cell view not adjusting to the column or is the column not adjusting to the table view?

Comment: The NSTableView has Autoresizes Subviews enabled, and the NSTableColumn is currently set to Width 331 (>40, <1000 Constraints). Of course, the NSTableColumn doesn't allow Autolayout constraints to be added - but it has been dragged to be the same width as the table in IB.

Comment: From the view debug, it looks like there's no such thing as a column when it's run - but the discrepancy is between the tableCellView.width and tableRowView.width.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - I think another part of the auto layout was infecting the table:

I have two boxes, side-by-side in the window, each with a table inside it. Each box had defined leading and trailing constraints, and were set to be of equal width as each other.

With doing nothing else to resolve the problem, I changed this so I had a vertical guide line centred in the view, and each box has a defined leading and trailing constraint between the view edge and the guide line - so I don't have to set the boxes as equal width.

Now my cells *nearly* resize completely correctly. The remaining issues I can live with for now:

- The cells start off too narrow, but if I resize the window width to compress the cells, they then follow the window width correctly if I expand it;
- At some point near the minimum width, horizontal scrollers briefly appear in the table views as I change the window width.

Hope this might help someone else.